# How to add Razorpay SDK in Xamarin Froms IOS as after installing the cocoapad and build is generated some errors are refecting

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, razorpay

I have install the cocoapad and and all but the build message show succeed and we got these types of errors
[image]